# Is there a reason why Pages are not publicly_queryable?

Tags: wp-query, pages, query

I am building a segmented search (by post type) with the ability to filter to a specific post type and realized pages were not publicly queryable. What I know I can do is the following:

```
function fix_page_query() {
    if ( post_type_exists( 'page' ) ) {
        global $wp_post_types;
        $wp_post_types['page']->publicly_queryable = true;
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'fix_page_query', 1 );
```

which does allow them to use `post_type` as a query var, but are there any shortcomings to doing this? Was there a specific reason they are not by default? I did see [this ticket](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18513) about the subject, but could not decipher a clear answer. Thanks!

Comment: I think Sergey answered your question there.

Comment: The "clear answer" was the patch he provided.

Comment: @BrianFegter Sergey [said](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18513#comment:3) what I knew (you can't publicly query them by `post_type` in this case because `publicly_queryable` is false), but I'm asking if there is a shortcoming to adding this in (as the action I have above does). Again, I am looking for clarity on the subject, so saying "Sergey answered your question here" doesn't help me as that is the confusing part.

Comment: It is confusing, but I think his answer is appropriate though the logic is extremely confusing in core.

Comment: @BrianFegter Then to clarify on my behalf, "Pages are not publicly queryable, but if you would like to make them (using a method similar to what I did in the example function), then that's fine, up to you." Is that correct? Nothing's going to... blow up

Comment: Correct. :) It won't affect anything negatively from my view.

Comment: There we go! Ha appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this one out - you can set Pages to be `publicly_queryable` using the function provided above.